# Can you have global util functions across all your cloud code methods?

Tags: parse-platform

I have a couple of functions that I am calling in every cloud code definition, can I pull them out into the global scope and use them across all the cloud code definitions?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes.  Parse uses node, and node allows for modules.  [See here](http://nodejs.org/docs/v0.3.2/api/modules.html).

In a nutshell:

```
// in some file, lets call it 'cloud/common.js'

exports.foo = function(x) {
    return x+1;
};

// in some other cloud file

var common = require('./common');
var bar = common.foo(1);  // bar will be 2
```